# Custom UIButton Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, ios9

I am trying to convert my project to Swift 2.0. I have a custom UIButton that is now causing an error when I try to build. 
My code is: `var myButton = MyCustomButton.buttonWihType(.Custom) as UIButton`

This is working with my project in Swift 1.2 but now does not work. The button uses a UIButton file to draw it called `MyCustomButton`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
var myButton = MyCustomButton(type: .Custom)
```